# ConditionalOnExpression fails to compare configuration property to enum type, works as string

Tags: spring-boot, spring-el

I want to load a `@Configuration` class based on an enum in properties file, so I have the following class:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{ ${demo.spel.demo-enum} eq T(demo.spel.DemoEnum).VALUE }")
public class DemoConfig {}
```

And I have: `demo.spel.demo-enum=value` in `application.properties`

This does not work, and throws the exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'value' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?

The odd thing is, that if I add single quotes to the property part, and a `toString()` to the enum part of the expression, there is no exception, the condition is true, and the bean is created (verified by checking console output in debug logging):

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{ '${demo.spel.demo-enum}' eq T(demo.spel.DemoEnum).VALUE.toString() }")
```

**Questions:**

Why is comparing an enum like this fails ? How come Spring can successfully convert the values and compare as string but not as their types ?

This is on Spring Boot 2.0.4

Comment: why don't you use **ConditionalOnProperty** like `@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "demo.spel", name = "demo-enum", havingValue="VALUE")` ?

Comment: That is what I eventually ended up using. I know how to work around that, but my questions specifically ask why does this fail, and how come it works when converted to String values :) I could see myself using this feature of enum to property comparison in a conditional expression, if this would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be pretty obvious, really.

Consider the following Java code:

```
foo.equals(DemoEnum.VALUE)
```

It would require an object `foo`, perhaps a field on `this`:

```
this.foo.equals(DemoEnum.VALUE)
```

If your property placeholder evaluates to 'foo', your first SpEL expression is the equivalent of

```
#this.foo eq T(DemoEnum).VALUE
```

So SpEL looks for a property `foo` on `#this`

**EDIT**

If you create a Class:

```
public class Foo {

    @Value("${some.property}")
    private DemoEnum enum;

    public getEnum() {
        return this.enum;
    }

}
```

And add a bean to the context called "foo" you could then use

```
foo.enum eq ...
```

Since `#this` is a `BeanExpressionContext` allowing you to reference other beans.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In your example, this makes perfect sense anyway. Lets say `this` has field `private DemoEnum foo = DemoEnum.VALUE;`, and checking `foo.equals(DemoEnum.VALUE)` would return true. Additionally, this doesn't explain why when transformed into a string value, the expression returns true.

Comment: No because when evaluating `#{...}`, `#this` is a `BeanExpressionContext` - it allows you to reference beans using `someBean.someProperty`. See my edit.

Comment: `>...doesn't explain` - yes it does; you are now comparing a String with a String. You could also use `T(DemoEnum).valueOf('${some.property}') eq T(DemoEnum).VALUE` to compare 2 enums.

Comment: So the `BeanExpressionContext` doesn't actually have a field that holds a reference to that enum value initialized by the properties, but a string value that represents the enum ? (in my code, the `@ConfigurationProperties` is also `@Component`, if that matters).

Comment: Properties are simply String values; Spring can apply conversion on them (such as my `@Value` example) if it has enough information. In the case of SpEL, properties are simple Strings since there is nothing to provide conversion hints. With `#{$some.property} ...}`, the property value is considered a bean name; hence, the SpEL expression will look for a bean called `value` in the application context. With `#{'${some.property}' ...}`, the property value is treated as a String literal.

Comment: Okay, I understand this much better now. Please just verify I understood this right: Basically it is impossible to expect a property from a `yml`/`properties` which are effectively Strings to reference an actual enum object and perform a comparison based on type, regardless of a class with `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Comment: One final question please: changing the expression from the property to the actual class field (`#{demoProperties.demoEnumField ... }`) results in false because it is null when the conditional is evaluated ?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. for your second comment, the field shouldn't be null if configured correctly because SpEL will `get()` the bean from the context, which will trigger it's autowiring. The conversation is getting too long (the SO admins will bark at us). If something is still not working as you expect, start a new question and show all the relevant configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
I had a feature, which was enabled by default. To disable it, application config file, should have it disabled explicitly. `demo.feature.disable:true`

I had a spring bean conditional on this property (enabled by default).

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{ ${demo.feature.disable} != true }")
@Component
public class FeatureModule {
}
```

The problem was, when `demo.spel.value` was not defined in the config file - `application.yml`, initialization of this component will fail with

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
```

To solve it, I provided default value.

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{ ${demo.feature.disable:false} != true }")
@Component
public class FeatureModule {
}
```

Now, when I test it.
By default this component is initialized.

If config file does not have `demo.feature.disable`, this component will be initialized.

If config file has `demo.feature.disable:true`, this component will not be initialized.

If config file has `demo.feature.disable:false` this component will be initialized.